# Problem in using Ocean's Browsercaps in ASP.NET app to detect spiders

Tags: asp.net, browsercaps

while studying a way of properly detecting crawlers on our ASP.NET application, I came across [Owen Brady's broswercaps](http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/) project.

In order to use it, I did this:

1. Created App_Browsers folder
2. Created Spiders folder in the above
3. Downloaded [OceanSpiders.browser.xml][2] and renamed it to OceanSpiders.browser

so, the final final looking like App_Browsers/Spiders/OceanSpiders.browser

I do have NET Framework 4 installed on my dev machine, but targeting NET Framework 3.5

The problem is a parser error: 'The browser or gateway element with ID 'docomon505i' cannot be found.'

I did google/search on SO, but could not find a solution, hence my reason for posting.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the web server is running against 4.0 run time and not the 3.5 run time, as it is reading the new Browser files which do not have docomon505i definition in them.

Comment: Hello there, Owen.
Thank you for the response.
Besides making sure that I'm targeting 3.5 framework (e.g. RightClick on Project -> Property Pages -> Build -> Target Framework), is there anything else I should do?

Comment: I'm also having the same issue with no luck finding a fix.  I am targeting 3.5 as well and when I look in the "docomo.browser" folder located in \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers, I do see the docomon505i parent.

Also, when I switch to 4.0 and try to use the 4.0 browser file, I get a similar error but with parentID="Default"